# 5v clock signal to 24v

Tags: relay, clock

I have a 555 timer clock output controlling a few things,  one of them is the coil of a 24v relay.  How can I take the 5v coming from the 555 and pump it up to 24v. ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyRO5T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I am doing is using the clock cycle to turn relay on/off . Then the 5v threw the contacts is being counted. Thus if I turn on off the relay 100 times, I should get 100 counts at the counter.  The logic works for a 5v relay, but unsure how to change this for a 24v relay.

Thanks
Glen

UPDATE
Added circuit as suggested, now the relay will get 24v across coil when signal is high and 16v when signal is low(not low enough to turn off relay). Below is image of circuit. 
[image: updated Circuit]

Comment: Do you have a 24V power supply? Also, relays bounce, so your counter may be way off.

Comment: I do have a 24v power supply, also the bounce I have taken care of. Just not showing it in circuit , by using a RC circuit.

Comment: You're not only trying to "pump up" the voltage, foremost you're trying to push more **power** through the relay coil than your 555 can supply. You'll need to switch a more powerful 24V supply, e.g. with a low-side switch in the shape of an NPN transistor or an n-channel MOSFET

Comment: ANd don't forget a flyback diode

Comment: Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx4D1.jpg

Comment: @Trevor so in this image VS is the 24v and the input to transistor would be the 555 clock. So simple, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really MUST use a 24V relay, or any relay really, you should use either an NPN or N-MOSFET driver like this..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuIe6f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But that really is not the best way to clock a counter. Relays bounce and can cause your counter to miscount. I am assuming you are using a relay for reasons of isolation. As such using an opto-coupler would be better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuKyNO.png)</sup>

Comment: The relay is what is being checked.  the 555 , one path goes straight to counter, other goes threw relay to counter.  I cycle it 99 times and make sure both counters are same , if not relay is sticking.  For bounce, i added a RC circuit to contact side.

Comment: Right now after trying this, I get at the relay coil 23volts when 555 signal is high, and 16 volts when its low.  not sure why i get the 16volts when low.. But that 16 volts is enough to keep relay energized.  Any thought on why there is 16 volts and not 0.

Comment: 555 output may not be low enough. Using an n-mosfet would be better.

Comment: @user41758 out of curiosity, what value did you chose for the base resistor.

Comment: 1k resistor , i have a circuit of what i have now. But not sure if its ok to post it or not on original question.

Comment: @user41758 you can tag it to the end under an EDIT or UPDATE heading.

Comment: @user41758 with a darlington like that use a much larger base resistor